# WHERE clause makes LEFT JOIN work like an INNER JOIN

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2010

I am trying to left join three tables with a where clause.  In the first example
the query results in an inner join.  If I take out the where clause it results in a left join, but in includes records outside the desired date range.

I'm using Microsoft Access 2010 and Visual Basic 2010.

```
strQry = " SELECT tblUnits.UnitNumber, TenantName, SchedRent, SchedCAM, sum(AMOUNT) as SUMAMOUNT " _
     & " FROM ((tblUnits  LEFT JOIN tblTenants ON tblTenants.Unitptr = tblUnits.ID) " _
     & " LEFT JOIN tblTrans ON (tblTenants.ID = tblTrans.id)  ) " _
     & " WHERE  (tblTrans.PostDate BETWEEN #" & txtStartDate.Text & "# AND #" & txtEndDate.Text & "# )   " _
     & " GROUP BY  tblUnits.UnitNumber, TenantName, SchedRent, SchedCAM " _
     & " ORDER BY tblUnits.UnitNumber "
```

In the second example it works perfectly, but only joins two tables

```
  strQry = " SELECT U.UnitNumber, sum(AMOUNT) as sumamount " _
 & " FROM tblUnits AS U  " _
     & " LEFT JOIN " _
     & " ( " _
     & " SELECT * " _
     & " FROM tblTrans " _
     & " WHERE  (tblTrans.PostDate BETWEEN #" & txtStartDate.Text & "# AND #"      & txtEndDate.Text & "# )   " _
     & " ) as X " _
     & " ON U.ID = X.ID " _
     & " GROUP BY U.UnitNumber "
```

I can't get the syntax correct when I try to join the third table

Comment: Come on list the query.  Don't make us read the = ".  It makes posting an answer more difficult.    I pass.

Answer (score 0):

Try `WHERE tblTrans.PostDate IS NULL OR ...`

As it stands, your LEFT JOIN includes tblUnits rows for which there is no matching tblTrans row.  Then your WHERE clause eliminates these rows.

Comment: Access allows an "OR" but not an "AND" in the ON clause.

Comment: @Larrythebruin OK, I've removed that alternative

Answer (score 0):

The following works

```
 strQry = " SELECT U.UnitNumber, T.TenantName, T.SchedRent, T.SchedCAM, sum(AMOUNT) as SUMAMOUNT " _
        & " FROM ((tblUnits AS U  " _
        & " LEFT JOIN  tblTenants as T ON U.ID = T.UnitPtr) " _
        & " LEFT JOIN " _
        & " ( " _
        & " SELECT * " _
        & " FROM tblTrans " _
        & " WHERE  (tblTrans.PostDate BETWEEN #" & txtStartDate.Text & "# AND #" & txtEndDate.Text & "# )   " _
        & " ) as X " _
        & " ON U.ID = X.ID) " _
        & " GROUP BY  U.UnitNumber, TenantName, SchedRent, SchedCAM " _
        & " ORDER BY U.UnitNumber "
```